# Отображение маркеров

Tags: flutter, yandexmapkit, mapkit

на Яндекс картах в debug mode отображаются все маркеры (их 15) а на release mode - apk файле отображается только один (точнее самый последний в списке). Из за чего это может быть? Flutter application
C сервера приходит список заведений, делаю loop и беру lat lon у каждого из них, getPlaceMarkObject возвращает лист с 15 item))

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не забывайте добавлять к вопросам пример кода и привязывать все важные метки. Учитывая то, что Яндекс Flutter не поддерживает, имеет смысл сразу подвязывать метку флаттера, чтобы к вопросу подключались специалисты этого фреймворка.